# how to connect an Oracle database with hadoop to display the resulat a request?

Tags: sql, oracle, hadoop, driver

I want to display the result of a query using hadoop
can you help me and give me an example

Comment: please do some R&D on sqoop to connect Oracle Db.if you face any problems ,then post them.

Comment: "Hadoop" is an infrastructure for processing data.  It is not a method for displaying results.  The question makes no sense.

Comment: I want to use only hadoop and oracle and I have no idea about it